# Play Framework and Dependencies

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I started looking at Play 2.0.
I first intended to use it with Java since there are some Java APIs that I would like to interface with.  But after reading about Scala, I thought I'd give that a try.

I came across the 'Grizzled Scala' library and 'Grizzled SLF4J' and would like to add this to a Play framework project, but am not sure how.
I'm using Eclipse and installed the Scala IDE.

Instructions are here:  http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/
It assumes that you're using Maven, which I'm not, or sbt, which I think that Play does.

I see the following sbt command:
sbt> ls-install grizzled-scala

I'm not able to start a pure sbt shell, although the manual says that play is an sbt shell -- it doesn't seem to understand the ls-install command.  It seems I need to install the ls SBT plugin.

Am I going down the right path on this?

Comment: And BTW, you can very well code in Scala and work with Java API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play2 uses Sbt as [a build system](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Build) / [dependency management](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTDependencies).

If you want to add the "Grizzled Scala" [dependency](http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-scala/#using_with_sbt), edit the `project/Build.scala` file of your Play2's project, and add the dep in the appDependencies section:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "org.clapper" %% "grizzled-scala" % "1.0.13"
)
```

Comment: where do these dependency jars are saved?

Comment: They are saved in your local Ivy folder, ie `<YOUR_PLAY_HOME>/repository/local`